# Организация генерации миниатюр в PHP

Tags: php, изображения, проектирование, thumbnails

**Дано:** некое PHP-приложение, куча картинок, используется некий шаблонизатор.

**Требуется:** организовать генерацию миниатюр обеспечив максимальную производительность, правильное использование кэша браузера и регенерацию миниатюр при изменении исходных картинок.

**Как это "обычно" делается:**

Есть некая функция `resize(image, size)`, которая реализует масштабирование картинки так как нам нужно.
В шаблоне имеем что-то вроде `{ resize source_image 100x100 }`, что в свою очередь делает следующее:

1. Строит путь до миниатюры `thumb_file_path`.
2. Пытается найти `thumb_file_path` на диске.
3. Если файл не существует физически генерирует картинку `resize(source_image, 100x100)`
4. Возвращает URL, соотвтетсующий `thumb_file_path`.

**Недостатки** данного подхода, от которых хотелось бы избавиться

1. Каждый запрос на каждой миниатюре **не** дёргать файловую систему с проверкой наличия миниатюры.
2. При обновлении исходного изображения, его миниатюры должны "прозрачно" 
   обновляться.
3. Возможность физической генерации **после** отдачи страницы юзеру.

**А также**

- Сами миниатюры должны отдаваться веб-сервером, PHP только URL'ы выдаёт.
- Не использовать `memcached`... Не знаю, сколько раз не пинал его, так и не удавалось стабильной работы достичь, может причина во мне...
- Сгенерировать картинку нужно с помощью `resize()` - сторонние генераторы не подходят.

Answer (score 3):

В memcache хранить картинки - это ещё тот изврат. Или не это имелось ввиду?

В целом, можно сделать все без кода. На базе самого вебсервера. Для этого можно использовать nginx с правильно настроенным модулем. На [хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/94435/) есть статья, как все настроить и использовать. Думаю, это то, что Вам нужно.

Более детально в архитектуру. Для картинок я бы выделил отдельный поддомен (что то вида img.yoursite.com). Это позволит запустить nginx прям на основной машине. Пока нагрузка будет маленькой - этого будет достаточно. Когда нагрузка выростет, можно будет перенести это все на отдельный сервер и только поправить запись в dns. Также, если все это будет на отдельном домене/вебсервере (пусть даже на одной физической машине), это позволит более точно все настроить (что бы конвертация картинок не съедала все ресурсы).

Comment: Не. В memcache конечно не сами картинки хранить, а URL-ы уже проверенных миниатюрок, 1-ый проход - дёргаем файловую систему, запоминаем, дальше ФС не дёргаем.

Comment: Насчёт nginx, не знал. Спасибо за ссылку. НО, банально, водянной знак не наложишь. В общем случае желателен произвольный алгоритм, то бишь только волшебная `resize()` умеет это делать :)

Comment: Если сильно нужны водяные знаки и другие гадости на картинках, то просто берется модуль, упомянутый в статье, благое дело для него есть [исходники](http://lxr.nginx.org/source/src/http/modules/ngx_http_proxy_module.c) и допиливается напильником и лобзиком до нужного состояния.

Comment: Если говорить про напильники, то я лично бы на node отдельный сервак написал, вместо того чтобы компилять nginx. Направление мысли понятно. Спасибо. Может кто предложит решение в рамках PHP.

Comment: вот только работать оно будет "сильно быстрее":) то есть, тупить будет сильно быстрее.
Когда мне нужно было что то очень подобное (на вход 4 картинки, на выход - комбинация 2на2), то я сделал свое приложение, которые слушало http и все конвертировало. А уже админ завернул nginx на него.